# $Rad(I)$ is an ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, radicals

$$Rad(I)=\{a \in R | \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } a^n \in I\}$$

$R$ is a commutative ring, $I$ is an ideal.

To show that $Rad(I)$ is an ideal of $R$, we have to show that for $a,b \in Rad(I)$ it stands that $a-b \in Rad(I)$ and for $r\in R$ it stands that $a\cdot r\in Rad(I)$, right??

When $a,b \in Rad(I)$ we have that $a,b \in R$ and $a^n, b^m \in I$.

$a-b \in R$.

But how can we show that $(a-b)^k \in I, k \in \mathbb{N}$ ??

Comment: Hint: The ring is commutative... Newton's Binomial

Comment: Doh, I accidentally closed using the wrong link. This is certainly a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Note $J$ this radical of $I$. If $a\in J$ and $b\in A$, $a^n\in I$ for some $n>0$ so that $(ba)^n = b^n a^n \in I$ because $I$ is a ideal, so that $ba\in J$. Now, if $a,b\in J$, whose respective powers $a^n$ and $b^m$ are in $I$, then by commutatativity we have $(a+b)^{n+m} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+m} {n+m \choose k} a^k b^{n+m-k}$ by the well-known *binomial formula* and this is in $I$ because in the sum, each term is in $I$, and this is because for each $k$, either $k\geq n$ or $n+m-k\geq m$ which ensures that one the two factors of the term are in $I$, so that the other is also in $I$ as $I$ is an ideal. This shows that $a+b\in J$, so that $J$ is an ideal of $A$.

Comment: @RobertLewis And do you believe in typos ?

Comment: It seems we are of the same faith in the matter of typos.

Comment: @RobertLewis By the way, in don't believe that in general $(a - b)^{m + n}= \sum_0^{m + n} \dfrac{(m + n)!}{i!(m + n - i)!} a^i b^{m + n - i}$ as you wrote. ;-)

Comment: @RobertLewis ANd obviously, I prefer to consider $a+b$ instead of $a-b$, but that's a matter of taste. ;-)

Comment: You know, you are right!  The Typo Faith is Strong!  I will edit for pennance!

Comment: I like $a + b$ better myself, but . . .

Comment: My first comment was screwed up.  Repaired version:
I do believe that, in general, $(a−b)^{m+n}=\sum_0^{m+n} \frac{(m+n)!}{i!(m+n−i)!} a^i (-b)^{m+n−i} \ne \sum_0^{m + n}= a^i (-b)^{n+m−i}$. But the basic idea of your answer seems correct. Cheers!

Comment: Robert, what is $A$ defined to be?

Comment: $A$ is the ambient ring.

Comment: Hm, i've never heard of an Ambient Ring before. Scary. I suppose it is equivalent to my question in the other thread? Why are you using an ambient ring? That is, motivation?

Comment: By ambient ring, I mean a ring all your ideals belong to.

Answer (score 2):

The binomial theorem holds in any commutative ring $R$.  Thus

$(a - b)^k = \sum_0^k \dfrac{k!}{i!(k - i)!} a^i (-b)^{k - i}. \tag{1}$

Now if $a, b \in R$ with $a^n, b^m \in I$, then taking $k = m + n$ yields

$(a - b)^{m + n}= \sum_0^{m + n} \dfrac{(m + n)!}{i!(m + n - i)!} a^i (-b)^{m + n - i}, \tag{2}$

and for every $i$, $0 \le i \le m + n$, either $i \ge n$ or $m + n - i \ge m$.  In the former case, $a^i \in I$ and in the latter, $b^{m + n - i} \in I$.  Thus every product $a^i (-b)^{n + m - i}$ occurring in (2) is also in $I$, whence $(a - b)^{n + m} \in I$, and that's how it is shown.

It is also easy to see that if $a^n \in I$, then $(ra)^n = r^n a^n \in I$, whence $ra \in Rad(I)$ for $r \in R$, completing the demonstration that $Rad(I)$ is an ideal.

Comment: Cool, so now, your answer is a copy of mine ! ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen:  That's funny, I thought yours was a copy of mine! ;)

Comment: @This would be possible only in case of time reversibility. ;-)

Comment: @RobertGreen:  My answer presents a standard argument in my own words, as I presume does yours.  The basic math occurs in many testbooks, so the question of copying seems mooted.  I don't think PCT applies to posts on the SE network.

Comment: @RobertGreen:  sorry if I seemed grouchy.  Been a long day and I just got off work and am sort of tired. ;-) ;-) ;-) !!!