# Showing $\sqrt{N}$ is an ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I wish to show that if $N$ is an ideal of a commutitive ring $R$, then $$\sqrt{N} = \{a \in R \mid \exists k \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \textrm{s.t. }a^k \in N\}$$
is an ideal of $R$.

Is this sufficient: " If r is an element of $R$ and $a$ an element of √N with $a^n \in N$ then $(ra)^n = r^na^n$ is in $N$, so $ra$ is in $√N$. 
"?

Can someone show an example where ideals of a commutative ring, $\sqrt{N}$ may not be equal to $N$?

Comment: For closure under sums [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1154008/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, but it is not sufficient, as you also have to check that $x,y\in\sqrt{N}$ implies that $x+y\in \sqrt{N}$. For this, see my answer here :

[$Rad(I)$ is an ideal of $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1127291/radi-is-an-ideal-of-i/1127300#1127300)

(Note that the $R$ there is your $A$ here.)

Now as you saw, $N$ is always contained in $\sqrt{N}$, but the inclusion can be strict, for example : the radical of $4\mathbf{Z}$ in $\mathbf{Z}$ is $2\mathbf{Z}$. Note $J$ the radical of $I = 4\mathbf{Z}$ and let's show $J = 2\mathbf{Z}$. Take $x\in J$ so that there is an $n\in\mathbf{N}^*$ such that $x^n \in 4\mathbf{Z}$. Then $4$ divides $x^n$, so that $2$ divides $x^n$, and as $2$ is prime, this implies that $2$ divides $x$, that is, that $x\in 2\mathbf{Z}$. We have shown that $J\subseteq 2\mathbf{Z}$. Inversely take $x= 2y\in 2\mathbf{Z}$. Then $x^2 = 4 y^2 \in I$, so that $x\in\sqrt{I} = J$, and we are done.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you. I'll continue reading your post in the other thread.

Comment: I would by the way appreciate people to avoid correcting right things to replace them by wrong ones : "you're right" means "you are right", correcting it by "your right" makes no sense.

Comment: @Ozera Np ! If your happy, just validate the answer, so that the case is closed. ;-)

Comment: There is a time limit in accepting answers. The question will be closed in < 2min

Comment: Oh really, why will it be closed ? (I mean, I may contribute here, by I'm not hyper aware of all habits here)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, it's my fault ! By "case is closed" I meant : the answer is accepted so people know that an answer has been accepted.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Robert, what is $N^*$. Do you mean $\mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: $\mathbf{N} = \mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$. $\mathbf{N}^* = \mathbb{N}^* = \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Comment: Aha. Okay, thank you.

Comment: Usually, I mean historically, people wrote $\mathbb{N}$ on a blackboard because it was quicker to wrote that writing $\mathbf{N}$. But the notation passed to typesetting and books. ;-)

Comment: I had thought you were just keeping to your typo faith as in the previous thread. Neat information!