# Showing √I is a Subgroup of Prime Ideal in R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let R be a commutative ring with identity 1 not equal to 0. Let I subgroup of R be an ideal.

show that if p a subgroup of R is a prime ideal containing I, then √I is a subgroup of p.(√I is defined here [Showing $\sqrt{N}$ is an ideal of $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171827/showing-sqrtn-is-an-ideal-of-r))

what are some properties of prime ideal that will be helpful in approaching this?
I am still new to the concept of ideals, so any suggestions would be a lot of help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathfrak{p}\subseteq R$ be a prime ideal with $I\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$, and let $a\in\sqrt{I}$. Then by definition, $a^n\in I$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, $a^n\in\mathfrak{p}$. But since $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, $a\in\mathfrak{p}$ (either $a$ or $a^{n-1}$ is in $\mathfrak{p}$, and induction will show that in fact $a\in\mathfrak{p}$). Thus, $\sqrt{I}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}$. This sort of argument is typical with prime ideals, considering their defining property is $ab\in\mathfrak{p}$ implies that $a\in\mathfrak{p}$ or $b\in\mathfrak{p}$.